# Problem choosing a random word from a list of words in C

Tags: c, random

I am in an intro C programming class, and am trying to program a game of hangman. I am currently on the VERY early stages though, and hoping to get help with the part where I have the computer choose the word to be used for the game. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <string.h>  
#include<string.h>  
#include <time.h> /* contains prototype for function time */  
#define MAX 10  

int main()  
{   
int randnum;
char gameword[MAX];
randnum = 1+(rand() % 20);
printf("%d\n", randnum);

if (randnum=1)(
    gameword= char word1[MAX]=who);
if randnum=2(
    gameword=char word2[MAX] = lives);
if randnum=3(
   gameword=char word3[MAX] = in);
if randnum=4(
   gameword=char word4[MAX] = a);
if randnum=5(
   gameword=char word5[MAX] = pineapple);
if randnum=6(
   gameword=char word6[MAX] = under);
if randnum=7(
   gameword=char word7[MAX] = the);
if randnum=8(
   gameword=char word8[MAX] = sea);
if randnum=9(
   gameword=char word9[MAX] = absorbant);
if randnum=10(
   gameword=char word10[MAX] = and);
if randnum=11(
   gameword=char word11[MAX] = yellow);
if randnum=12(
   gameword=char word12[MAX] = porous);
if randnum=13(
   gameword=char word13[MAX] = is);
if randnum=14(
   gameword=char word14[MAX] = he);
if randnum=15(
   gameword=char word15[MAX] = sponge);
if randnum=16(
   gameword=char word16[MAX] = bob);
if randnum=17(
   gameword=char word17[MAX] = square);
if randnum=18(
   gameword=char word18[MAX] = pants);
if randnum=19(
   gameword=char word19[MAX] = crabby);
if randnum=20(
   gameword=char word20[MAX] = patties);

printf("%c", gameword);
return 0;
}
```

I am getting errors like:

> line 19 suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
>
> line 20 expected expression before 'char'
>
> line 64 expected ';' before '}' token
>
> line 64 control reaches end of non-void function

Any help would be great. I have a long way to go on this assignment, but I'm getting stuck very early here.

Answer (score 2):

Some things:

- in C (and many other language) the assignment operator `=` is not the same as the equality `==` operator. First one is used to assign a value to a variable while second one is used to check for equality
- the code `gameword=char word2[MAX] = lives);` doesn't make much sense, what you want to do? you want to choose between a list of words. You should first hard code (I suppose) the list of words with something like

  `char *words[]={"foo", "bar", "baz", "lol"};`

then you generate the random number and choose the right string, eg `words[randnum]`

Answer (score 0):

```
// ...
if (randnum == 13)
  gameword = "is"; else
// ...

printf("%s\n", gameword);
```

And here is your code, more C-like:

```
#include <string.h>  
#include<string.h>  
#include <time.h> /* contains prototype for function time */  

int main()  
{   
  int randnum;  
  char gameword[10];

  randnum = 1 + (rand() % 20);  
  printf("%d\n", randnum);  

  switch (randnum)
  {
    case 1:
        gameword = "who";
    break;  

    case 2:
        gameword = "lives";
    break;

    case 3:
        gameword = "in";
    break;

    case 4:
        gameword = "a";
    break;

    case 5:
        gameword = "pineapple";
    break;

    case 6:
        gameword = "under";
    break;

    case 7:
        gameword = "the";
    break;

    case 8:
        gameword = "sea";
    break;

    //...
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to spot a lot of your errors just by eyeballing correct code and making a visual comparison. You're using the wrong symbols, you've got mismatched parentheses, and the `gameword=` lines are plain bizarre looking.

#### If statements

```
if (randnum=1)(
    gameword= char word1[MAX]=who);
```

- Use two equal signs for comparisons.
- You need a balanced set of parentheses around the conditional expression.
- Use curly braces `{` and `}` to surround the code inside the `if` statement.
- You need to quote strings like `"who"` and `"pineapple"`. Double quotes.
- Your assignment statements are not even close, sorry. What you were aiming for is `gameword = "who";`
- Except with `gameword = "who";` you will get an error about illegal assignment to an array. It's too much to go into here, but suffice it to say that you need to use the `strcpy` function: `strcpy(gameword, "who")`

Taking in all those comments, here's a valid if statement you can use as a model:

```
if (randnum == 1) {  
    strcpy(gameword, "who");
}
```

#### Printing

```
printf("%c", gameword);
```

The `%c` format specifier is for printing single characters. You are trying to print a string, so use `%s` instead. Also it'll look better if you add a newline character `'\n'` at the end.

```
printf("%s\n", gameword);
```

#### Random numbers

Once you get this to compile you'll end up seeing the same word printed every time. The `rand()` function is only a pseudo-random number generator. The random numbers it returns aren't truly random; they are actually generated using a fixed algorithm. This means it will always return the same random numbers in the same order unless you **seed** the random number generator.

A decent seed is the system clock. The clock changes regularly so you can use it to feed in a varying seed number to the RNG. Insert this line at the top of your program before you call `rand()`:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Answer (score 0):

First off you'll want to use `==` as a conditional operator where you have `randnum=1`

`==` compares, `=` assigns

Next, you have an issue with syntax.  It should be `if (randnum == 20)`

But, you'll probably want to place your strings into an array.  So you can just use an array offset.

Answer (score 0):

Use `else if` instead of second and next `if`

Answer (score 0):

You should be using else if instead of if, if, if, if... This way once it hits the correct option, it won't loose moretime checking the others.

Also, = is assignment, == is used to compare.

Then, except the first "if", all the others are missing the conditions:

```
if randnum=2(
    gameword=char word2[MAX] = lives);
```

Should be

```
if (randnum=2)
    gameword=char word2[MAX] = lives);
```

Answer (score 0):

`=` is the assignment operator.  `==` tests for equality.  You want to change your code to the following:

```
if(randnum == 1)
    gameword = "who"; 
else if(randnum == 2)
    gameword = "lives";
else if(randnum == 3)
    gameword = "in";
```

and so on.  Remember that each `if` statement is going to be followed by a single line statement or a block of code enclosed in braces.

Your print statement should be as follows:
    `printf("%s", gameword);`
`%s` tells `printf` that you are printing a string.  `%c` will only print a single character.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>


int main (void) {
    const int numberOfWords = 3
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL)); //generate a random seed based on time so it's different every time!
    int ran = rand()% numberOfWords; //Generate a random number between 0 to numberOfWords - 1
    char *hello[] = {"One", "Two", "Three"}; //Fill in the array with words
    printf("%s", hello[ran]); //Print a string and choose the nth element from the array
    //remember arrays are 0 based!
    return 0;
}
```

Aside from all the mismatched brackets, and == and things, using 20 `if` statements isn't the way to go. What you really want is to have a character array and use your random number as an index. I would highly suggest you look over the above code carefully and not just copy and paste it. I know I shouldn't be giving you all the code, but so many if statements are just *painful*.